# DJI SDK Maven Repo not finding Artifact

Tags: maven, dji-sdk

I am trying to add the `source jar files` to a project on which I am working.

I have added the dependency into the `pom` file for the project. 
I have manually added two repos into the `om` file. This the `maven central` and also the `maven.google`.
I have tried a forced an update but still not able to get the source for the `SDK`. The `SDK-provider` is fine.

The following `artifacts` could not be resolved:

```
com.dji:dji-sdk:jar:4.7.1, com.android.support:appcompat-
v7:jar:25.3.1, com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:jar:1.0.2: Could not find artifact com.dji:dji-sdk:jar:4.7.1 in my-repo1
```

(https://maven.google.com) -> [Help 1]

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Could you paste the parts of your pom.xml where you defined your dependencies and the repos? The settings.xml would also help, especially the repo part. Also: What's your working environment? Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Im using IntelliJ as the IDE. I have the following i the pom. <repository><id>my-repo1</id><name>Maven1</name><url>https://maven.google.com</url></respository><repository><id>my-repo2</id><name>Maven2</name><url>https://central.maven.org/maven2</url></respository>. I dont have other than the standard settings in the settings.xml.

Comment: SOLVED: Found that the dji-sdk maven pom, specifies the two dependencies which I am having issues with as a JAR <type>, where as they are actually an AAR. Since the repo does not have the JAR it fails, not that it says that in so many words. Edited the Maven POM and the error is gone.

Comment: You should write an answer and accept it to make the question appear as solved. It could be useful for other developers.